# Error messages with mustache and spring error tags

Tags: spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc, tags, mustache

I found the following documentation from Spring to validate forms easily. 
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-validating-form-input
Now I have the problem that I can't use the Thymeleaf error tags with Mustache. Does anyone have a solution, or an idea?

**This is the solution from the documentation**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${personForm}" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{age}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}" th:errors="*{age}">Age Error</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**A part of my edit.mustache file**

```
<form action="/event/save" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post">
    {{#event}}
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="title">Name</label>
                <input min="1" maxlength="60" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title"
                       placeholder="Titel" required
                       value="{{title}}">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That Spring guide uses dependency spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf which pulls in thymeleaf-spring package that has various helpers including piece code that enabled expression for `fields.hasErrors`.

There is no similar Spring library for Mustache, see spring-boot-starter-mustache.

Validation errors can be collected `BindingResult` and passed through `Model` to Mustache template for rendering.

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String checkPersonInfo(
        @Valid PersonForm personForm,
        BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model model
) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        var validationErrors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors()
                .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        FieldError::getField,
                        FieldError::getDefaultMessage
                ));
        if (!validationErrors.isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("validationErrors", validationErrors);
        }
        return "form";
    }
    return "redirect:/results";
}
```

Matching Mustache template

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="{{#personForm.name}}{{personForm.name}}{{/personForm.name}}" /></td>
            {{#validationErrors}}
                {{#name}}
                    <td>Name error: {{name}}</td>
                {{/name}}
            {{/validationErrors}}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="age" value="{{#personForm.age}}{{personForm.age}}{{/personForm.age}}" /></td>
            {{#validationErrors}}
                {{#age}}
                    <td>Age error: {{age}}</td>
                {{/age}}
            {{/validationErrors}}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/build.gradle#L9

thymeleaf-spring
https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/blob/3.1-master/thymeleaf-spring6/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/spring6/expression/Fields.java#L57

spring-boot-starter-mustache
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-mustache/build.gradle